# Include content types from content type hub in doc library template / site template

Tags: 2013, document-library, content-type-hub

Previously if you wanted content types and fields commonly available across your farm and automatically included in document libraries, you'd (pay someone a lot of money to) copy Microsoft and create a fields feature, ctypes feature, and library feature and put them in a custom site template. If content type hubs are supposed to let you centrally manage this stuff without messing around on the back end, can you do the same with them - ie, automatically include hub ctypes in new libs?

Comment: Do you mean to say, you want to add content types from the HUB in your new libraries? or is it something else you want to ask?

Comment: I want the content types to be in new libraries automatically. I don't want it to be a manual exercise. When users create a library, the content types (and fields) should already be there. And when users create a new site, it should have a copy of the same library by default.

Comment: Someone mentioned an event receiver on list added. I'm thinking that's probably how it has to be done. Add them thru code when the list is created

Comment: Yes, event receiver will do your job.